# Are lens hoods a must?

Tags: lens, lens-hood

I see most professional photographers use lens hoods. Why is that? Do they use them for something apart from preventing scratches, etc.?  Are lens hoods a must for all lenses?  What should I consider before buying them?

Comment: Related: [What does a lens hood do?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/662)

Comment: Related: [Is there any downside to using a knock-off lens hood?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/38520)

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to use a lens hood in low light?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/7086)

Comment: Related: [This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42071/15871) to [How durable are external lens coatings?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42069/15871)

Comment: On the opposite side of the coin: [is uv filter a must?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90191/15871)

Comment: Related: [What is causing the strange lighter circles in images taken with my Canon 15-85?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46049/15871)

Comment: Related: [How important are lens hoods on ultra wide zoom lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88307/15871)

Comment: Related: [Will a filter cause more or less damage when lens is dropped?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39879/15871)

Answer (score 14):

Flare in an optical system results when stray light (non-image forming) comingles with the image-forming light rays. A lens hood diminishes the ill effects of flare by shielding the lens from unwanted peripheral light rays. Every picture will benefit if a lens hood is mounted. This is because stray light enters the lens barrel, and is reflected off the polished surfaces of each individual lens within the optical system.  This stray light bathes the image sensor (or film), and this reduces the contrast of the visual image. Flare light has many sources -- thus mounting a lens hood won’t eliminate flare.

The chief countermeasures are flat-black paint applied to the inter surfaces of the camera and the lens barrel together with a coating on each lens. A thin mineral coat is applied to all polished optical surfaces. It is the thickness of the coat that does the trick when it comes to mitigating internal reflections within the optical system. A coat thickness of ¼ wave length of light will dampen reflections. Often each lens will have multiple coats, one for each color (frequency) of light.

In summation, flare is devastating; it robs our images of contrast. The lens hood is just one additional measure we can bring to bear.

Comment: Flare is an evil contrast killer; every little bit helps. Not to mention that a big hood on a big piece of glass looks neat, and differentiates a pro from a non-pro :)

Comment: *Every picture will benefit if a lens hood is mounted.* Perhaps, but the degree to which a specific picture will benefit can range anywhere from miniscule to being transformative depending on the conditions under which the picture is made.

Comment: I've also used cheap third party hoods that were made of smooth plastic so shiny that the reflections off the inside surface of the hood actually *added* flare. So I'm not so sure that *Every picture will benefit if a lens hood is mounted* is entirely true unless it is qualified in some way such as *Every picture will benefit if a properly designed lens hood is mounted.*

Answer (score 6):

Using a properly sized and oriented lens hood reduces the probability of negative circumstances such as [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare) and some forms of physical damage to the lens (a lens hood could possibly increase the probability of other forms of physical damage so each photographer should conduct their own risk assessment).

As is typical for most photographic equipment, a manufacturer's lens hood designed specifically for the lens is likely to provide the reasonable performance in common use cases and it may require less research regarding the technical lens hood requirements for a particular lens. Compared to a third party lens hood, a manufacturer's lens hood is more likely to utilize a lens specific mounting rather than filter thread mounting.

Things I look for:

1. **Attachment** The generic attachment is screw on via the filter threads of the lens. However, manufacturers may incorporate bayonet or other mounts on the body of a lens allowing quicker attachment of the hood and avoiding the need to share the filter threads with filters or mount filters in the lens hood.
2. **Shape** Wide angle zooms may require a petal style lens hood to avoid capturing the lens hood in the corners of the image because this will create vignetting.
3. **Size** A screw on lens hood needs to be sized to the same diameter as the lens threads (without opening the adapter can of worms). Some screw on lens hoods have different diameters at the rear (male) and front (female) and therefore will require different lens caps and filters (or adapters).
4. **Material** This is a matter of personal preference (tradeoffs). Hard materials like plastic or metal may provide more protection from some forms of physical damage. Collapsible rubber lens hoods take less space in a camera bag when left attached.
5. **Price** More or less, there's some correlation between quality and price but that's on average and like everything, it's a tradeoff. A cheap rubber hood may actually meet a particular photographer's needs more readily than a bespoke hood that is objectively better by many common metrics.
6. **Aesthetics** There's nothing wrong with selecting camera equipment based on aesthetics. Typically there is a lot of hard work and deliberate effort behind the design of camera equipment and appreciating that is no different from appreciating the work and effort that goes into the aesthetics of a particular photograph or painting or piece of music or building or garden.

Comment: Using the wrong lens hood can get you some neat vignetting when done intentionally. Got one of my favorite pics of my daughter that way. :)

Comment: @FreeMan So can using the right lens hood not properly twisted all the way on.

Answer (score 3):

Many full-time pros I know don't use hoods. I mostly don't use them myself.

However, there are times I do use them, these are: (1) hoods are indispensable in inclement weather, although on a wide-angle lens such as the Canon 16-35 f/2.8, a hood offers little rain cover; (2) hoods stop flare caused by strong oblique lighting; and, (3) hoods offer some mechanical protection from knocks and scratches.

The disadvantages of hoods are: 
(1) They add length and bulk to the lens.  This can be a pain when trying to work quickly in fast moving situations with multiple lenses as you may need to remove the hood, or reverse it, to get the lens into your bag or belt-pouch.
(2) As I often work very close up to people, I think the camera is intimidating enough without some large contraption added to front, so for the sake of being less intrusive, I'll often avoid using a hood.
(3) I find flare caused by strong oblique light is rare, so I often don't feel there's any need to use a hood.  Of course, being in the UK, may have something to do with that. If I lived and worked somewhere sunnier, I may have a different experience.
(4) I think modern lens coatings go a long way to eliminating flare meaning hoods can be redundant.  Some lenses suffer more than others, so let experience be you guide here.
(5) I'm a minimalist by nature and hate fiddle-faddle.  So if I can do away with something in my workflow, I do.  Having said that, I've not thrown away any of my hoods, and normally carry them, but only use them if I feel there is a real need to.
(6) And finally, sometimes flare actually adds to the shot.

My rule, if I had one, would be not to use a hood, unless there was good reason to use one.

Answer (score 2):

They are an equivalent of you shielding your vision against a bright light using your hand or by wearing a cap, resulting in a better image quality. You can't put any lens hood on any lens, so always search for hoods made for your specific lens and you should be fine.

They are not a must, but they can help a lot, as they offer a good physical protection against scratches and bumps, and against flare caused by bright sources of light (sun, studio lights, etc.).

Comment: do they improve image quality in all situations or only in flash photography and in direct sunlight?

Comment: @StrangePhoton, well, they improve the quality every time there's a risk a light could hit front of your lens. 'How much' is a different question though and depends on many factors (quality of your lens, direction and strength of light etc.). Many people follow a simple rule - have them on unless you have a good reason not to use them. One such situation is when you have a short macro lens and you need to get as close as possible. A lens hood can block light to your subject and even prevent you getting close enough.

Comment: @StrangePhoton A uniformly bright sky of thin cloud can be worse then direct sunlight as there's a large bright area to cause problems.

Comment: @StrangePhoton Please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/41724/15871) for examples of how exposure level can affect the perceived effect of flare from strong light sources in the field of view.

Answer (score 2):

For me, one of the joys of photography is capturing the pureness of kids at play, which often means a long lens (so they are less aware and don't ham it up) and being down at their level, often sitting on the ground. Over the course of nearly 40 years of photography, I can't tell you how many times the lens hood has prevented a misbehaving child from reaching my lens with his icing- or whip cream-covered fingers.  When you are hunched down, and looking through a long lens, your situational awareness of little Bobby winging his way in from the side is non-existant.  The first you know something requires quick action is when that dark object is coming in on the lens barrel.

As an eyeglass wearer, I am constantly reminded that light sources close to the plane of my eyeglasses cause haze unless I clean the lenses diligently.

So whenever I'm asked the age-old question: "filter or hood?" I answer "hood."