# How do I prevent washed out photos with an Olympus Mju II on sunny days?

Tags: film, exposure, point-and-shoot, olympus, film-cameras

Whenever I use my Olympus Mju II with ISO 200 film on a warm very sunny day, the photos come out washed out. I need help with what proper film to use.

Comment: Can you post an example? It's hard to guess otherwise. I've never used this camera, but online reviews report that the metering is good, and film should provide decent latitude in any case. Does the camera perform perfectly in other situations?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I appreciate it, as far as my liking it does perform very well once during daytime and I used superia 400 that time and photos came out like pastel colours which I like and I used a V5 50 scanner all the time.  I don’t think it. Takes UV filter. I also used it once with a agfa vista 200 and it’s very washed out. I will upload some photos that I took with it but I think I washed out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "veiling glare"? How does it affect my photos, and how can I avoid it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99591/what-is-veiling-glare-how-does-it-affect-my-photos-and-how-can-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 2):

Use higher iso film, for example 50 or 100 iso.
Use higher camera f-stop, eg f8.
Use UV or Polarising filter.

Comment: Thanks. I wii try next time

Comment: That would be lower ISO... just sayin...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly due to UV rays. Use an UV filter.

Comment: The camera doesn't appear to take filters.  Camerapedia: [Olympus mju-II](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Olympus_mju_II)